# How reliable is the action_name method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

How can I ensure that the controller.action_name returns correct information? I rely on that to generate user-friendly messages in the menu bar. Consider the following scenario.

The action_name method works great when I use:

```
redirect_to edit_profile_path # I get action_name as "edit" in my ApplicationController
```

But it does not yield the information I need when I use the following:

```
render :action => "edit"  # The action_name shows as "get" instead of "edit"
```

Is there a way I can use render action and still get the correct action_name?

Thanks,
Tabrez

---- code snippets in response to Mischa's comment ----

This is what I have in the controller:

```
def update
    if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile]) 
        format.html { 
            flash.now[:notice] = 'Profile was successfully updated.'            
            render :action => "edit" 
        }
end
```

I am not redirecting because I still want the user to stay in the edit mode.

In my application helper I have code to the following effect:

```
if(action_name == "edit" && (can? :read, l_disp_object) )  then
    path_links_subheader.concat(link_to 'Show Saved Version', :controller => controller.controller_path, :action => :show) 
end
```

Basically, if the user is in edit mode, I want the "Show Saved Version" link on the menu.  But, when I use the "render :action" syntax, the action changes to "get", which makes sense based on what Mischa mentioned (action being a misnomer there..).  So, is there a way I can accomplish this without issuing a redirect?  The only reason I am not already using redirect is that the logic for retaining the current tab for the user works with render action.  I might have to rewrite it if the only possible way to accomplish this is via redirects.

Comment: What is in your routes.rb file for that action?

Comment: Hi Frederick - Please see the updated version.  I was able to trace down the issue to the way in which I display the edit view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naming is a bit confusing, but `render :action => "edit"` renders the edit *view*. It doesn't have anything to do with the *controller action* edit. `action_name` is reliable, but for the above reason you cannot rely on it. Open a new question and/or share some more code for suggestions how to fix your problem.

Comment: Hi Mischa - thanks for the response.  I added the code snippets and the reasons why I have not already changed over to redirects.  Please review and let me know if there is a workaround.

Comment: Mischa - Thanks for the answer.  At least I know now why it did not work.  I found an alternative for saving the tab state, which now allows me to use redirects.  It would be great to have some way of using the render view statement without losing track of the action that rendered the view.  So, if it comes to you, do share.  Thanks again!